# find css selector to add to python script using selenium

Tags: python, html, css, xpath

okay guys been out of coding for a while and im trying to get back in because i love it

currently im writing a python script and im having trouble finding the correct way to click button ive tried several different times and this is where im stuck at.

Add to Bag

when copying css selector:

`#dwfrm_product_addtocart_d0rmouqnbpev > div > div.pdp-button-block > button.pdp-add-to-bag.add-to-cart.pid-19CE-ac0eff0691331d3dc991483b06`

when copying xpath:

`//*[@id="dwfrm_product_addtocart_d0byuazkjuyr"]/div/div[5]/button[1]`

code i have in script:

`python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwfrm_product_addtocart_d0byuazkjuyr']/div/div[5]/button[1]")[0] 
    python_button.click()`

ive tried different things and currently having a hard time

Answer (score 0):

Few points in the line used:
`find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dwfrm_product_addtocart_d0byuazkjuyr']/div/div[5]/button[1]")[0]`

1. `find_element_by_xpath` returns a WebElement and not a list of WebElements. So you can remove the [0] as it picks the 1st element matching the xpath.
2. Or you can use `find_elements_by_xpath` if you want to match a list and pick one element using index.
3. The last part of id looks randomly generated, so better use contains instead of going for an exact match.

You can verify in console if the locator used is correct(using `$$` for css and `$x` for xpath). If it is correct, then see if any other element is overlapping the element that you're trying to click and try clicking on that.

Hope this helps!
Good luck